# What is a basic method to get User Age Group on the web like Google Analytics?

Tags: machine-learning, google-analytics, artificial-intelligence

Let's say I want to know a user age group based on their browsing history on the web. What are the information that I need to collect to classify a user age group?

I can get the following information.

```
Their visited webpages
Their time spent on webpages 
Their device information
Their IP address
The time slot of a day they are online
```

What other information could be useful to classify user age group?

Please guide me to a correct place to start learning about User Age classification.

Thanks.

Comment: Most of Googles info is collected though the DoubleClick cook I believe.   This might help as well  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en

Comment: @DaImTo, yeah cookie. but how do they use cookie to do it? I just need a head start.

Comment: First create a user base of a few billion people that accept cookies from your company domain and register an account for your services, and make them enter their personal data. Then get back to SO for further instructions.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, didn't know Stackoverflow has mean people. I have access to 30million people cookie.